# Create a process to update child record when the parent is updated

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

You've been given a requirement to keep Contact addresses in sync with the Account they belong to. Use Process Builder to create a new process that updates all child Contact addresses when the address of the Account record is updated. This process:

- Can have any name.
- Must be activated.
- Must update Contact mailing address fields (Street, City, State, Post Code, Country) when the parent Account shipping address field values are updated.
- NOTE: You may have to deactivate the validation rule for the Contacts object (created from a previous challenge) in order to complete this challenge.

I developed some `Process Builder`
[image]

[image]

[image]

And when I check this Process Builder I see the below error:
[image]

**I have activated this process already, but not working.**

Comment: I am really exhausted in solving this issue. Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

This challenge is completed when Contact mailing address fields (Street, City, State, Post Code, Country) are updated on changing the parent Account's shipping address. So to do this I created a Process Builder UpdateChildOnParentUpdate. 
And here is the step by step solution.

1. We have to create Process builder on Account because we checks the changes on Account.
2. Check if there is any change in the shipping address(Street, City, State, Post Code, Country) of Account and if there is any change in any of them field we set boolean is true.(All these condition are in AND condition).
3. Finally we update Contact mailing address fields (Street, City, State, Post Code, Country) by taking the reference of its Account(Parent).

**Here all the images of process builder according to above steps**

[Checks if there is any change in shipping address of Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQFww.jpg)

[Update all contact's mailing address attached to updated Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D4RH.jpg)

**Cheers , Salesforce is Awesome !! **

Comment: Nope its not working. Something very wired issue with my org.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Billing Address Fields use Shipping State, City, Zip code and Country fields for Action Group. Refer the Attachment.[Action Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3BP1.png) I hope this will help you

Answer (score -1):

While adding the object, Account (1st step), click Advance, then click yes for Recursion.

[image: Refer Below Image for visual guidance]